# To get sum of previous days in ssas

Tags: ssas

please  I am trying to get the last 60 days before a month starts

I  have a set that is returned from the query below

```
SELECT
   non empty
   [Measures].[TRANSACTIONS Count] on 0,
   non empty ([TRANSACTIONS].[Days].[Days],                                                                                                [TRANSACTIONS].[Transaction Month].[Transaction Month])  on 1 from [cube]
```

I can get the cumulative count of last 60 days before month 2 by hard-coding the day of transaction of start of next month like below

```
  WITH MEMBER
 [Measures].[Cumm Account Count]
AS
(
    AGGREGATE( [TRANSACTIONS].[Days].CurrentMember:NULL ,[Measures].[TRANSACTIONS Count])
)

 SELECT
   non empty [Measures].[Cumm Account Count] on 0,
   non empty [TRANSACTIONS].[Days].&[3]:[TRANSACTIONS].[Days].&[3].lead(60) on 1 from  [cube];
```

please how can i achieve the above result without having to use the day numbers, I tried to use the tail function (to get the months and start date)

```
non empty tail(
([TRANSACTIONS].[Days].[Days],
tail([TRANSACTIONS].[Transaction Month].[Transaction Month],1)
),1)
```

,So I am hoping if I can use this with a sort of range function for 60days, then to get the next month will simply be a case of getting the tail(xx,2) with the range of 60days but it wont work because the range function  accepts members only , please any guidance or where to check

Answer (score 0):

If I am clear with your question, you need the transaction count for last or next 60 days right?

You might need to replace the dimensions and measures with your own, but this can be done with the Adventure Works cube as follows:

```
WITH 

    MEMBER [Measures].[Last60Days] AS 
    SUM
    (
        [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.lag(60) : [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER,
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    )

    MEMBER [Measures].[Next60Days] AS 
    SUM
    (
        [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER : [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.lead(60),
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    )

SELECT 

    {[Measures].[Last60Days], [Measures].[Next60Days]} ON 0,

    [Date].[Date].[Date] ON 1

FROM [Adventure Works]
```